How is the formula for off policy lambda returns derived (formula inside)
In particular, I am speaking about the formula $(12.26)$ in Suttons Book : Introduction to Reinforcement Learning:
$G_{t}^{\lambda a} = R_{t+1} + \gamma_{t+1}(\bar{V}(S_{t+1}) + \gamma_{t+1}\rho_{t+1}[G_{t+1}^{\lambda a} - \hat{q}(S_{t+1}, A_{t+1})]) $
which combines off policy traces with control variates. What I currently understand is this:
We can rewrite the $\lambda$-Return, which is generally defined as
$G_t = (1-\lambda)\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \lambda^{n-1}G_{t:t+n}$
recursively as
$G_{t}^{\lambda} = R_{t+1} + \gamma (\lambda G_{t+1}^{\lambda} + (1-\lambda)V(S_{t+1})) $
Moreover, the $n$-step Return, which is generally defined as (note, that the n-step Return appears in the $\lambda$-Return formula above)
$G_{t:h} = R_{t+1} + \gamma G_{t+1:h}$
can be extended for off-policy methods, by introducing importance sampling weights $\rho$ and using control variates (equation $(7.13)$ in Sutton book)
$G_{t:h} = \rho_{t}(R_{t+1} + \gamma G_{t+1:h}) + (1-p_{t})V_{h-1}(S_{t}) $
And some how, combining this definiton of the $n$-step Return, with the recursive definition of the $\lambda$-Return, should give the formula $(12.26)$, but unfortunately I have no clue how.
